# looking for the solution of : Svg on click should open anchor tag

Tags: html, css, svg, anchor, mailto

i am trying to wrap an svg inside an anchor tag or vice versa so that when i click on the svg icon it should open the anchor(mailto)link but the svg fails to become clickable. Its very challenging and frustating i spent a whole day trying to figure out solution and i havent found any.

Also will it be possible to use img instead of an svg to make this happen?

Here's the anchor tag and svg :

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mailtoui@1.0.3/dist/mailtoui-min.js"></script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.2.0/tailwind.min.css">
```

```html
<a class="mailtoui w-8 h-8" href="mailto:zaki.faiz4@gmail.com?subject=Something">  
 <svg class="mx-auto animate-pulse mailtoui " viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg " fill="black" width=30 height=30><title/>
  <g data-name="mail email e-mail letter" id="mail_email_e-mail_letter"> <path d="M28,13a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v8a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H6a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V14a1,1,0,0,0-2,0v8a3,3,0,0,0,.88,2.12A3,3,0,0,0,6,25H26a3,3,0,0,0,2.12-.88A3,3,0,0,0,29,22V14A1,1,0,0,0,28,13Z"/> <path d="M15.4,18.8a1,1,0,0,0,1.2,0L28.41,9.94a1,1,0,0,0,.3-1.23,3.06,3.06,0,0,0-.59-.83A3,3,0,0,0,26,7H6a3,3,0,0,0-2.12.88,3.06,3.06,0,0,0-.59.83,1,1,0,0,0,.3,1.23ZM6,9H26a.9.9,0,0,1,.28,0L16,16.75,5.72,9A.9.9,0,0,1,6,9Z"/>
 </g></svg>
</a>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Do you have an email client installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes i have outlook on windows. @Mr T

Comment: i have figured out now that the svg is only becoming click-able when i scroll the page.

Comment: In order to unserstand what is happening give the `<a>` a background color. You may need to give the ancor the same width and height as the svg element and display:block